# How can I highlight newly added table rows in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have a main function where this components is called.

```
import React from 'react'
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-components'

const FinalResponse = (props)=> {
  const rows = props.data
  const columns = //columns values
  return (
    <div>
      <DataTable data = {rows} columns = {columns}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The props are data fetched from a flask API using axios in useEffect.
The data is confirmed to be updated correctly in the API as well as the frontend.
How can I highlight the recently updated rows in a color?
Recently updated means that updated in the last 30 seconds

Comment: If your objects have an attribute with the last updated time you can identify the last updated items. Then you can review in documentation how to show a custom component (highlighted) in the Cell or the Row, or maybe pass a style object. Read here, I hope it helps you: https://react-data-table-component.netlify.app/?path=/docs/api-columns--page

Comment: Please edit to add how you determine and track the "30 seconds" - what should happen if the API takes more than 30 seconds to return data?  How have you attempted your "highlight"?  What is meant by "useEffect" here, is that supposed to mean some code not included that is important?